# how to mount and read from the .img file used by usb_gadget/g_multi/mass_storage?

Tags: mount, usb-device, loop-device

the pocket beagle, using debian9.9, shows up as a mass storage device on my windows machine. I have found the backing file (i'll call it a drive) used by the mass storage device. I would like to mount this drive and copy a file from it to the home directory. Unfortunately when I mount the drive I find that anything I put on it while in MSD mode is gone. What could be wrong?

The pocket beagle uses a g_multi gadget configured for ethernet, a serial port, and a mass storage device. The gadget is configured on boot by the following script: `/opt/scripts/boot/am335x_evm.sh`. I believe I should be able to access the drive before the g_multi gadget is configured, as the drive would not be in use at that time. I set up the following experiment:

I created a FAT32 partition in `/root/data/backing_file` and pointed the symlink in `/var/local/bb_usb_mass_storage.img` to it.

I can then plug in the board, make a file on the drive, and see the file there when I power cycle the device. However, when I put the following code at the start of `am335x_evm.sh`, the drive appears to get wiped.

```
losetup -o 1048576 /dev/loop0 /root/data/backing_file
mkdosfs -F 32 /dev/loop0
mount -t vfat /dev/loop0 /mnt/loop
ls /mnt/loop >> /var/log/messages
umount /dev/loop0
losetup -d /dev/loop0
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that I needed to create the backing storage as follows:

```
losetup -o 1048576 /dev/loop0 /root/data/backing_file 
mkdosfs -F 32 /dev/loop0  # note: only do this once!
mount -t vfat /dev/loop0 /mnt/loop
#put something in /mnt/loop
umount /dev/loop0
losetup -d /dev/loop0
```

I then needed to access the backing storage like this:

```
losetup -o 1048576 /dev/loop0 /root/data/backing_file 
mount -t vfat /dev/loop0 /mnt/loop
# take something from /mnt/loop
umount /dev/loop0
losetup -d /dev/loop0
```

I needed to create a partition table for the backing storage, and on that partition, create another partition to act as the storage. Instead, I was deleting my 'storage partition' every time I attempted to access it, by calling `mkdosfs`.